# Generating static HTML on build time in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a bit of data stored in a file that I would like to display on a Razor Page in my project. The obvious thing to do would be to just read the file in the `.cshtml.cs` file, pass it in the model, and display it. That, or caching.

The file, however, won't change often (if at all), and any time it would change, would be accompanied by the code of the app itself changing, so a build would be necessary one way or another.

That's how I got the idea of somehow generating the desired HTML on build time.

I know that, on build time, `.cshtml` files are compiled into regular C#, and I was looking for a way to, perhaps, hook into this process somehow. Alas, without much success.

My other attempt was a `.razor` file, rendered in a `Static` way, with data fetched in `ObInitializedAsync()` which was supposed to run only once per component. However, I think that hosting this component in a Razor page interfered with it somehow, and the code was running on every page load. That, or I misunderstood the lifecycle in the first place.

I even went as far as making a `.cs`-only component and manually using the `RenderTreeBuilder` from an overridden `BuildRenderTree`, but it also seems to render per page load.

Lastly, I briefly considered using a source generator to create a partial, but alas, source generators can't read files, so that attempt also failed.

I'm, quite frankly, out of ideas at this point. Hence the question, perhaps someone else had the same issue, or knows something I don't.

Comment: Not clear what is your issue.  From the beginning, it seems you want to store something in static file and dynamic call it. What does the other idea mean? Which one is your requirement?

Comment: @Rena my issue is getting data from a file, and including it into the generated HTML on build time, not on run time

Comment: Hi @Angius, so could you pls share what is your file like? And what data you want to get from this file? Also where do you want to locate it to the html?

Comment: @Rena Let's say it's a text file with `flabbergasted beaver` string inside, and I want to display it inside some `<h1>` tag

Comment: Hi @Angiius, you can create a static class(e.g named `HtmlExtension` class) with static method(e.g. named `GetFile`), in this method you could return string data by using code `return System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C://path/example.txt")`. Then in the view you can call the method and display the result by using `@{var data = NamespaceOfStaticClass.HtmlExtension.GetFile();}<h1>@data</h1>`.

Comment: @Rena Sure I can. But it will run every time the page is rendered, which is not my goal

Comment: Hey, thinking a lot about that last days. Something like what NextJS does (generate static html at build time, allowing even fetch data in that process), would be very nice using Razor as the template engine. I guess it is possible using MSBuild Tasks that could use some RenderToString method to save those files that could be deployed to a CDN. If you integrate that with HTMX, it could have amazing results.